# How can I read the file selected by the File Dialog box that opens in Azure Notebook using python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter, azure-notebooks

After I select a (csv) file from the file dialog, how can I read such file? The interface shows that the file does not exist.

With the code :

```
input_form = """
    <div style="border:solid navy; padding:20px;">
    <input type="file" id="file_selector" name="files[]"/>
    <output id="list"></output>
    </div>
    """

javascript = """
    <script type="text/Javascript">
      function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
        console.log('Executing orig')
        console.log(files)
        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        var f = files[0]
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                      '</_Mli>');
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
        var command = 'fname = "' + f.name + '"'
        console.log(command)
        kernel.execute(command);
      }

      document.getElementById('file_selector').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
    """

def file_selector():
    from IPython.display import HTML, display
    display(HTML(input_form + javascript))

f=file_selector()
```

I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICDqd.png), and the detailed error is

```
> IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-31-3234c73d353d> in <module>()
>       2 get_ipython().system(u'ls ~/library')
>       3 print fname
> ----> 4 df = pandas.read_csv(fname, index_col=False, header=0);
> 

> /home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc
> in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
> index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
> converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
> nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
> skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
> date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
> decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
> encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
> skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map,
> float_precision)
>     676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>     677 
> --> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     679 
>     680     parser_f.__name__ = name
> 
> /home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc
> in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>     438 
>     439     # Create the parser.
> --> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>     441 
>     442     if chunksize or iterator:
> 
> /home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc
> in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>     785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
>     786 
> --> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>     788 
>     789     def close(self):
> 
> /home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc
> in _make_engine(self, engine)    1012     def _make_engine(self,
> engine='c'):    1013         if engine == 'c':
> -> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)    1015         else:    1016             if engine == 'python':
> 
> /home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc
> in __init__(self, src, **kwds)    1706         kwds['usecols'] =
> self.usecols    1707 
> -> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1709     1710         passed_names = self.names is None
> 
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()
> 
> pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
> 
> IOError: File Sample.csv does not exist
```

How can I read the uploaded file? This problem has been bugging me for quite a while!!

Also, where is it uploaded once uploaded via the interface?